# How to reuse the layout of prototype cells in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have two TableViewControllers, and the layout of two prototype cells  are the same.  Is it possible to extract the layout so that I don't need to maintain multiple copies?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the cell via xib and you can reuse for the other table

To create xib right click on project on xcode choose new file then choose UserInterface choose view from it and save the name

then for the class of the xib file five your appropriate table view cell class and create outlet of the controls inside table view cell

to load the nib file on table view controller declare these two lines on your table view controller viewdidload function

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "your nib file name",bundle: nil)
erxTable.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "identifiername")
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

You can move those prototype cells into a xib file and register the UINib on each tableview.